# Parse first column of large Excel file using SAX parser

Tags: java, excel, xml-parsing, apache-poi, saxparser

Want to parse just the first column of the large excel file and store the data into a string by concatenating then using a comma (,) and here I am using Apache POI library and SAX parser to parse the excel file by converting into XML. As the XML file is having two same elements i.e. "Cell" inside the "Row" as the Excel file having two columns in it.
If anyone have an idea then please share.

```
   public void processFirstSheet(String filename) throws Exception{

        OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(filename);
        XSSFReader r = new XSSFReader( pkg );
        SharedStringsTable sst = r.getSharedStringsTable();
        XMLReader parser = fetchSheetParser(sst);
        InputStream sheet1 = r.getSheet("rId1");
        InputSource sheetSource = new InputSource(sheet1);
        parser.parse(sheetSource);
        sheet1.close();
   }

   public XMLReader fetchSheetParser(SharedStringsTable sst) throws SAXException, 
   ParserConfigurationException {
    XMLReader parser = SAXHelper.newXMLReader();
    ContentHandler handler = new SheetHandler(sst);
    parser.setContentHandler(handler);
    return parser;
}

private static class SheetHandler extends DefaultHandler{
     private SharedStringsTable sst;
     private String lastContents;
     private boolean nextIsString;
     private static int count=1;
        
     private SheetHandler(SharedStringsTable sst) {
            
            this.sst = sst;
     }
        
     public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name,
                Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        
    // c => cell
    if(name.equals("c")) {
     // Print the cell reference
     System.out.print(attributes.getValue("r") + " - ");
     // Figure out if the value is an index in the SST
     String cellType = attributes.getValue("t");
     if(cellType != null && cellType.equals("s")) {
        nextIsString = true;
      } else {
         nextIsString = false;
      }
     }
        
        // Clear contents cache
        lastContents = "";
            }
        
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name)
                throws SAXException {
            
            // Process the last contents as required.
            // Do now, as characters() may be called more than once
            if(nextIsString) {
                int idx = Integer.parseInt(lastContents);
                lastContents = new XSSFRichTextString(sst.getEntryAt(idx)).toString();
                nextIsString = false;
            }
            // v => contents of a cell
            // Output after we've seen the string contents
            if(name.equals("v")) {
                System.out.println(lastContents);
            }
        }
        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) {
        
            lastContents += new String(ch, start, length);
        }
        
        }
```

Comment: Check the `r` attribute of the cells for the cell reference, and ignore everything not in column A?

Comment: There is multiple rows about 7lkh and each row is having two cell tags as my excel file is having two columns in it so I just want to get the data of first cell from every row tag.